# OnTouchListener не работает в Service (на Xiaomi)

Tags: java, android, android-service

Есть сервис, который имеет свойства `View.OnTouchListener`
Дальше при создании сервиса:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            View touchView = new View(this);
            touchView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30));
            touchView.setOnTouchListener(this);
            WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            if (mWindowManager != null) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(30, -1, 2002, 262184, -3);
                mParams.gravity = 51;
                mWindowManager.addView(touchView, mParams);
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

Ну и сам перехват:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("touch","i'm here");
        return false;
    }
```

На всех аппаратах кроме Xiaomi событие тача работает, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, что это связано с тем, что доступ к `View` из `Service` является не очень хорошей практикой.

Сервис по определению является компонентой без UI и доступ из `Service` к UI можно делать на основе только строго специального вида усилий, типа: `Handler`, `Broadcast` или `Bound Service`, а то что вы пытаетесь сделать это просто хак, который иногда работает, а иногда не работает. Xiaomi значит молодцы, что у них в их прошивке это не работает :)

Ну и тем более опус типа:

```
View touchView = new View(this);
```

это тоже за гранью добра и зла.

Comment: Этот способ работает вообще на всех девайсах, от Alcatel 4.2 до Sumsung 7.1, а вот на сяоми - нет. Думаю, что это баг прошивки. Сейчас обнаружил, что так же там не работает AlertDialog

Comment: В `Service` вообще не должны работать любые виджеты по умолчанию и то что кое-где они работают - это как бы просто *вам повезло*

Comment: Серьезно? Повезло? Тестировалось на 500+ аппаратах, везде ок

Comment: @Magic абсолютно серьезно это недокументированная возможность и то что она работает на 500 аппаратах это ничего не доказывает

Comment: у ведре много чего недокументированного, но это работает. А проблему нашел, Сяоми при попытке изменить Type диалога или View - делает их невидмыми и неактивными, аля баг.

Answer (score -1):

Ответ нашел.
При попытке в сяоми использовать такой метод:

```
.getWindow().setType()
```

вызывает баг в системе, в результате чего AlertDialog или другое UI - становится невидмым

Comment: Перед тем как минусы ставить, убедитесь сами :/
На остальных аппаратах полет нормальный